# Change display depending on option selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I want to change 2 different div styles with jQuery. While the value is `div1`, div1 will be shown. And when the value is `div2`, div2 will be shown. I guess I can't do it with "if/else" in jQuery.

```
 <style>
  #div1 { display: block; background-color: red; height:300px; width:300px;}
  $div2 { display: none; background-color: blue; height:300px; width:300px;}
  </style>

  <select id="divit">
    <option value="div1">div1</option>
    <option value="div2">div2</option>
  </select>
<script>
    function displayVals() {
      var divoneValues = $("#divit").val("div1");
      var divtwoValues = $("#divit").val("div2");
      $("#div1").css("display", "none");
       $("#div2").css("display", "block");
    }     
    $("select").change(displayVals);
    displayVals();         

</script>
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
<style>
  #div1 { display: block; background-color: red; height:300px; width:300px;}
  #div2 { display: none; background-color: blue; height:300px; width:300px;}
</style>

<select id="divit">
    <option value="div1">div1</option>
    <option value="div2">div2</option>
</select>
<script>
    $("#divit").on('change', function() {
        var sel = $("select").val();
        if (sel=='div1') {
           $("#div1").css("display", "block");
           $("#div2").css("display", "none");
        }else if (sel=='div2') {
           $("#div1").css("display", "none");
           $("#div2").css("display", "block");
        }
    });     
</script>
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/H5aZz/)

Comment: thank you so much. its working very well. you have saved a man in the world :)

Answer (score 0):

`$('select').val()` returns the value of the selected option. So use a `switch` like this:

```
function displayVals() {
    switch ($("#divit").val()) {
        case 'div1':
            $("#div1").show();
            $("#div2").hide();
        break;
        case 'div2':
            $("#div1").hide();
            $("#div2").show();
        break;
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TimWolla/2KaTK/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is just a Javascript library. You still use Javascript code to access the jQuery library, so you can use any Javascript commands.

```
function displayVals() {
  var selected = $("#divit").val();
  if (selected == "div1") {
    $("#div1").hide();
    $("#div2").show();
  } else {
    $("#div1").show();
    $("#div2").hide();
  }
}
$("select").change(displayVals);
displayVals();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(){

    $(#divit).change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == 'div1'){
            $('#div2').hide();
            $('#div1').show();
        }else{
            $('#div1').hide();
            $('#div2').show();
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jpt8r/)**?

```
$('#divit').change(function(){
    $('div').hide();
    $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
  #div1 { display: block; background-color: red; height:300px; width:300px;}
  #div2 { display: none; background-color: blue; height:300px; width:300px;}
  </style>

  <select id="divit">
    <option value="div1">div1</option>
    <option value="div2">div2</option>
  </select>
<script>
    $('#divit').change(function(){
hideotherdivs($(this).val());
});

function hideotherdivs(div_not_to_hide)
{
$('#div1').hide();
$('#div2').hide();
//add all divs that have to be included in this scheme of hiding and showing
$(eval(div_not_to_hide)).show();
}
</script>
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

[DEMONSTRATION](http://jsfiddle.net/9nb2W/)

Answer (score 0):

This will **auto hide** any non selected options, while will show only the one selected, if you need to put more then two options

```
<style>
    #div1 { position: absolute; display: block; background-color: red; height:300px; width:300px;}
    #div2 { position: absolute; display: none; background-color: blue; height:300px; width:300px;}
    #div3 { position: absolute; display: none; background-color: green; height:300px; width:300px;}
    #div4 { position: absolute; display: none; background-color: pink; height:300px; width:300px;}
    #div5 { position: absolute; display: none; background-color: aqua; height:300px; width:300px;}
</style>

<select id="divit">
    <option value="div1">div1</option>
    <option value="div2">div2</option>
    <option value="div3">div3</option>
    <option value="div4">div4</option>
    <option value="div5">div5</option>
</select>

<script>

    function displayVals()
    {
        $('select#divit > option').each(function()
        {
            if ($(this).val() == $('select#divit').val())
            {
                $('#'+$(this).val()).css('display', 'block');
            }
            else
            {
                $('#'+$(this).val()).css('display', 'none');
            }
        });
    }     
    $("select").change(displayVals);
    displayVals();         

</script>

<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
<div id="div4"></div>
<div id="div5"></div>
```

**Just a side note:** please note that in your code you put a `$` in place of a `#` in your style part for `div2`
The correct would be `#div2 {` in place of `$div2 {`

Comment: oo yes i just see it. maybe it was the bug made me sick. because i have tried more of the comments. thank you :)

Comment: @user1162833 so go ahead and vote me up :) .. and check the correct answer too